# Android: Google Sign In Client always returns RESULT_CANCELED

Tags: java, android, authentication, google-oauth

I'm trying to add Google sign-in to my app. The Google sign-in popup does successfully show up. But after I sign in to any google account, `result.getResultCode()` in `onActivityResult` always returns `RESULT_CANCELED`.

First, I created the OAuth client ID credentials. One of type "Android" and another of type "Web application", and the SHA-1 that I used for the "Android" type is the one I got by running "gradle signingreport" in Android Studio.
[Google Cloud console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZmda.png)

Then I added the code to my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SignInClient oneTapClient;
    private BeginSignInRequest signInRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        oneTapClient = Identity.getSignInClient(this);
        signInRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
                .setPasswordRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.PasswordRequestOptions.builder()
                        .setSupported(true)
                        .build())
                .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                        .setSupported(true)
                        // Your server's client ID, not your Android client ID.
                        .setServerClientId(getString(R.string.web_client_id))
                        // Only show accounts previously used to sign in.
                        .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                        .build())
                // Automatically sign in when exactly one credential is retrieved.
                .setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
                .build();

        ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> activityResultLauncher =
                registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "result: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e("TAG", "" + result);
                        if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(() -> oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, result -> {
                    IntentSenderRequest intentSenderRequest =
                            new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(result.getPendingIntent().getIntentSender()).build();
                    activityResultLauncher.launch(intentSenderRequest);
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, e -> {
                    // No saved credentials found. Launch the One Tap sign-up flow, or
                    // do nothing and continue presenting the signed-out UI.
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage() + ", cause: " + e.getCause());
                }), 10000);

    }
}
```

The value of the string `web_client_id` is the Client ID that was created for the type "Android".

Comment: Anyone? Please need help!

Comment: Any chance you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

Two things to pay attention to:

1. Make sure your SHA-1 is set correctly in your Android credential. You can view SHA-1 by running `./gradlew signingReport` in your project directory.
2. Make sure `R.string.web_client_id` is set to the client id of the **Web Application's Credential** (Not the android one).